# Flow doesn't infer type correctly

Tags: redux, flowtype

I define an multiple subtypes in the Action creator in redux:

Action creator:

```
export type Action = { type: "SELECT", index: number } | { type: "OTHER" };
```

Reducer:

```
module.exports = (state: string = "", action: Action): string => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SELECT":
            return action.index;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

but if I define **SELECT** in a constant `const select = "SELECT"` and implement it in the code above  I obtain an error message:

```
property `index`. Property not found in object type
```

Note: Taking flow-pattern as it is F8 app:

> https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/actions/types.js

How should implement it by avoiding having "SELECT" keyword both in the action and in the reducer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would normally have another constant with the action type, which would be used for both your action and reducer.

```
const SELECT = 'SELECT';
```

or even better (to avoid any conflicts):

```
const SELECT = 'redux/<module>/SELECT';
```

In the same action file or in another (that's totally up to you). Then just export like `export const SELECT`, and import like `import { SELECT } from './constants'`.

You should also take a look at [redux-ducks](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux), might be of your interest.

**EDIT:**

They use [bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) to group all possible different action cases. That helps testing whether the code is syntactically correct with [flow](https://flowtype.org/) (by setting their dispatched actions to match type [Action](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/actions/types.js)). See their full explanation [here](http://makeitopen.com/tutorials/building-the-f8-app/testing/).

That does not take away the fact that they have to dispatch the action with their desired action type though. [login](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/actions/login.js#L116)

Comment: Thanks, but my question is focused on how flow understands and infere different types splitted by "or" operator.

Comment: @alejandrogarciarobles iinteresting question +1, had to do some research myself but it was worth it. Let me know if the edit part is all you were looking forward.